# Specifically, how would you compile a folder of decompiled actionscript back into a runable .swf

Tags: flash, compilation, actionscript, mxmlc, recompile

I know there is some information on compiling actionscript out there but i am finding it really hard to understand and I can't seem to get anything to work.

I have recently taken interest in a spirograph maker flash game and wanted to see see how it was coded. [Link if it helps](https://www.mathplayground.com/Spiromath.html)

I eventually found a decompiler which does what I want and was able to see all of the actionscript code.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTnYg.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHFYT.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux3dI.png)

However as you can see it is not a single file but a collection of libraries which is simply do not know how to recompile after editing. I have tried AIRSDK mxmlc compiler and flash develop but it's not obvious what I have to do.

Am I missing something? A very foolproof explanation will be much appreciated as I have tried to understand everything I've found and not getting anywhere for two days now and could really do with some help.

Comment: The sad truth about decompiling is that in order to properly understand someone else's code you need to already be on a higher level (as a developer) than you need to actually develop the same application by yourself. It would be easier for you (and faster) to read and understand math and geometry behind that spirograph and to develop your own application, then to waste days digging that alien code you don't understand anyway. Also, another thing about decompiled projects, there's absolutely no guarantee at all that script and assets are compilable in any possible way at all.

Comment: I actually think that the code is quite understandable. All I want to do is add some extra functionality and test it.